# Java not formatting date correctly

Tags: java, date, format

The code I've got should convert the date of birth input to DD/MM/YYYY format, which it does but for example when I input 20/08/2000 it sees the date as 3rd January.

```
System.out.println(this.dob);
DateFormat dateF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
Date birth = dateF.parse(this.dob);
System.out.println(birth);
```

Which outputs

```
20/08/2000
Mon Jan 03 00:00:00 GMT 2000
```

Comment: Why can't people learn the difference between `yyyy` and `YYYY`? Or why they don't even bother to recheck if their pattern is correct? Annoying.

Answer (score 4):

Using capital `Y`s in your format means something called the "week year".

Instead, use lowercase `y`s in your format, which means the year as you'd expect.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: When in August, the year and the week year are the same. The week year is the year that the week number belongs to; only around New Year may it deviate from the year (for instance if week 52 of the previous year extends into January).

Comment: @OleV.V. That may be true, but changing to `yyyy` corrects the output to the proper date.